# Getting Non matching row from mysql table using left join

Tags: mysql

I have a steps table in my DB. I want to fetch all the steps to be executed next for each operation (each step is attached to a operation). Steps are executed in sequence according to field step_number (type: decimal). Conditions are as follows

1- A step can be started if previous step of same operation is completed.

2- Steps belonging to same operation and having same integer value for e.g. 1.1 and 1.2 can run concurrently

3- If its first step of the operation then start it

```
SELECT 
        MIN(s1.step_number),
        s1.type,
        s1.operation,
        MAX(s2.step_number)
    FROM steps s1
    LEFT JOIN steps s2 
        ON  s1.operation = s2.operation
    WHERE 
        s1.state= 'not_started'
        AND s2.state != 'not_started'
        AND 
        (
            /* 1- A step can be started if previous step of same operation is completed. */
            (s2.state = 'confirmed')
            OR
            (
              /* 2- Steps belonging to same operation and having same integer value for e.g. 1.1 and 1.2 can run concurrently */
                s2.state != 'confirmed'
                AND CAST(s1.step_number AS UNSIGNED) = CAST(s2.step_number AS UNSIGNED)
            )
            OR
             /* 3- If its first step of the operation then start it */
            s1.step_number = (
                SELECT
                        MIN(step_number)
                    FROM steps s3
                    WHERE operation = s1.operation
                )
        )
    GROUP BY operation
```

The query is not returning rows matched by condition # 3 as these are already filtered out due to Left Join. Is there a alternate way to do this so I can get rows for all three conditions.

Comment: You could just include those rows into your result set by extending the `LEFT JOIN` with an `OR`-condition to match those missing rows from your 3rd `WHERE`-condition

Comment: @DrCopyPaste

Changed ON part to this

ON 
(
s1.operation = s2.operation
OR
0 = (SELECT COUNT(id) FROM steps WHERE operation = s1.operation AND state != 'not_started')
)

Seems to be working

Comment: just really read what you just wrote, this is not really what I suggested, I thought you would just include `OR s1.step_number = ( SELECT MIN(step_number) FROM steps WHERE operation = s1.operation)` into your `ON` from that `LEFT JOIN`